# How to plot this two variables piecewise function?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, piecewise

I was wondering if there is a suitable way to plot the function

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} x & y < x^3 \\\\ y & y \geq x^3 \end{cases}$$

Maybe with piecewise? But it's a two variables function, and the condition is itself reling on a function..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
f[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{x, y < x^3}, {y, y >= x^3}}]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Comment: Simpler: `Piecewise[{{x, y < x^3}}, y]` (using $y$ as the default result).